# Staging Site: Made Public - Security Questions

Tags: security, staging

Previously, our staging site has been locked down to local access only. We hired a third party developer to assist with [resolving a theme](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/223800/theme-unresponsive-in-wordpress-4-5-4-4-2-ok) via our 'local staging server' remotely. In order to grant them access, we made the staging server resolve externally with an A record in the DNS to the staging subdomain.

From my understanding this is not a best practice and I thought we needed to secure it further. Do I restrict access to the entire subdomain by IP or a Password, or is there a better method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whether or not you lock down a staging site really depends on how much you mind the public accidentally seeing a site that's a "work in progress". I'd usually consider it more of a branding decision than a security decision.

*(This of course wouldn't apply if you're in the middle of developing a secure application that might be buggy, but Wordpress theming - especially once it gets to the staging site - is unlikely to cause a security risk).*

One thing I would recommend doing is in Settings -> Reading, ticking the option that discourages search engines from crawling the site. The last thing you want is a site that's not complete showing up in search results.

Other than that, the only way for someone to find the site is to know the URL. For a temporary staging site, that's usually security enough.

If you're concerned, some quick ways to limit it further would be:

- Install a maintenance plugin (there's many available in the plugin directory). These work by locking down your site and showing a maintenance page to all but logged in users. So you can just create users in WP for those who you wish to give access to.
- Add IP blocking or password protection to .htaccess. This is also fairly easy to do, [this StackOverfow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4400412/1982136) deals with IP allowing and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5229803/1982136) walks through password protection.
- As an even quicker alternative to the first option, add `if( !is_user_logged_in() ){ die(); }` at the top of `header.php` in the theme. Then any unexpected visitor just sees a blank page. *(Thanks to [@shahar](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/13118/shahar) in the comments)*

If you discourage search engine crawling through that option on the Reading page, make yourself a note somewhere to turn it back on when you go live. There's almost nothing worse than forgetting that!

Comment: For blocking access to staging sites, I usually put `if( !is_user_logged_in() ){ die(); }` at the top of header.php. Then any unexpected visitor just sees a blank page.

Comment: @shahar Nice quick solution! I've added it to the the answer :)